# How to access query parameter in URL in angular (outside of the hash, non-html 5 mode)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a url:

http://localhost/myapplication?fruit=bannana

When I navigate to it in the browser... angular changes the URL to the following.

http://localhost/myapplication?fruit=bannana#/

My question is how can I access the "fruit=bannana"? I tried $location.search() and it does not seem to pick up the fruit=bannana.

My Reason for Needing to Do This:
$routeParams does not work for me is because I am using an authentication mechanism that drops the hashtag and everything after it (CAS) when the user goes to http://localhost/myapplication/#/fruit=bannana, the user is redirected to a login page, after logging in, the user is redirected back to http://localhost/myapplication/#/ (notice how none of the hashtag params were preserved).

If there is some workaround to this, it would be great. html5 mode on locationProvider does not work for me as I need this to work in IE9.

Comment: did  you specify query string in the route?

Comment: The query string is "before the #" and not actually part of the route. As stated in the OP, the query string cannot be after the "#", because the CAS authentication strips off any query params that are tacked on to the end of it when redirecting back from successful authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a js function I use to read `GET` variables.:

```
//gets a get variable "variable"'s value from url 
function getUrlVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

`variable` is the name of the `GET` var (in your case, `fruit`).

If you `var x = getUrlVariable('fruit');`, `x` would be `'banana'`

Let me know if you need more explanation?

Comment: This is correct. In angular, you may want to consider using the $window service instead of the global javascript window (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)